# Icons displaying divs on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few icons that enlarge on hover, they look somewhat like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tzx9R/).
I was trying to find a way to make them display a div underneath them, but I failed. I tried using Javascript but my skills are pretty low.
Does anybody has a way? This is the CSS I used for the icons,

```
.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -5;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
}
.icon:hover {
    width: 155px;
    z-index: 100;
    margin: -15px -22px -15px -13px;
}
```

And the HTML I used for one of them:

```
<img class="icon" src="http://goolag.eu/wita.png">
```

Comment: u want to display enlarge image on hover?

Comment: what do you mean by **display a div underneath them**

Comment: 1) "somewhat like this fiddle" is not a good example. make your own fiddle with code specific to your question. 2) showus what you have tried so far. "does anybody have a way" is not a question, of course someone has a way, but stackoverflow is not a tutorial website, show us what you have tried and we will help

Comment: Hello what is problem with your code? see jsfiddle . http://jsfiddle.net/AMbD3/1/  Everything is ok

Comment: This should pretty much show what I need, and tried to achieve.
http://i.imgur.com/w5uBoJq.png

Comment: @Banana , Dont u think u r being little rude to Asker?

Comment: @Banana That's my fiddle actually.

Comment: If you are using JQuery, you can use `$('.icon').mouseover(function(){ //here you can show the div });`

Comment: @Adrift Yes, I am going to try that out, thanks.

Comment: @TwixSK: You can also use positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/Tzx9R/7/

Comment: @Adrift Please put your answer as an actual answer, so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:before` or `:after` on the containing link to reveal a hidden element.

If you want to fade the element in with opacity you can use something like: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tzx9R/10/)

```
a {
    position: relative;
}

a:after {
    content: "Content here"; 
    background: lightgray;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px; left: 50%; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    height: 5em; width: 5em;
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
   -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
   -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
   -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);  /* used for dynamic horizontal centering */
    opacity: 0;
   -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    transition: opacity .6s ease;
}

a:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The only problem with the above is that if you hover over pseudo element itself it'll appear.

One way around this is to combine positioning & opacity: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tzx9R/9/)

```
a {
    position: relative;
}

a:after {
    content: "Insert content";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; left: 50%; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    background: lightgray;
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
   -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
   -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
   -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
   -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease, top 1s ease;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease, top 1s ease;
    transition: opacity 1s ease, top 1s ease;
}

a:hover:after {
    top: 150px; /* slide it down 150px on :hover */
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Note that if you only had an `<img />` (and no wrapping link) this wouldn't work because the behaviour of `:before` & `:after` is undefined when used on self-closing elements. Also the pseudo element in both examples will be clickable like the link, so this may or may not work for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

With a little bit of restructuring this can be accomplished easily with only CSS.

Put the icon and the `<div>` to show inside a containing `<div>` like so:

```
<div class="icon-container">
    <img class="icon" src="http://goolag.eu/wita.png">
    <div class="show-on-hover"></div>
</div>
```

And then use the following CSS:

```
.icon-container img {
    /* Normal image state */
}
.icon-container:hover img {
    /* Enlarged image state */
}
.icon-container .show-on-hover {
    /* Normal background div state */
    display: none;
}
.icon-container:hover .show-on-hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Notice that you are checking the container `<div>` for hovering rather than the image itself. This lets you easily apply styles to all the children of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tzx9R/4/)

**jQuery:**

```
$("a").on("mouseenter", function () {
    $("#bg-div").show();
}).on("mouseleave", function () {
    $("#bg-div").hide();
});
```

Basically saying for any anchor tag, show the div when the mouse enters, and hide the div when the mouse leaves.

This could be even shorter:

```
$("a").hover(function() { // When hovering
    $("#bg-div").toggle(); // Toggle the element's visibility
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create something like this:

```
//HTML

<div id="newDiv"> Whatever you want to include </div>


//CSS

#newDiv {
   display: none,
   ...
}


//Javascript with JQuery

$( ".icon" ).hover(function() {
  $( "#newDiv" ).css("display", "block");
});
```